# Kolmogorov forward equations of a simple birth process.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I have got a simple birth process such that $ q(n,n+1) = -q(n,n)= \lambda n$
I want to solve the KFE.
$d/dt.p_t(n,n) = -\lambda n p_t(n,n)$

$p_0(n,n) = 1$

$d/dt p_t(n,n+k) = -\lambda (n+k) p_t(n,n+k) + \lambda (n+k-1) p_t(n,n+k-1)$

$p_0(n,n+k)=0$

Take $n=1 $ and let $q_t(k) = p_t(1,1+k)$

A.  Then $d/dt q_t(k) =  -\lambda (1+k) q_t(k) + \lambda k q_t(k-1) $

$ q_t(0) = e^{-\lambda t}$

B. Then this gives
$q_t(k) = (exp(\lambda t) -1)^k exp(-(k+1)\lambda t) $

I follow this calculation up to the point I have labelled B. How do you solve the equation in A when we have $q_t(k)$ AND $q_t(k-1)$ involved?

Comment: Recursively: compute $q_t(0)$ (done), then plug it in the ODE involving $q_t(1)$ and $q_t(0)$, solve this for $q_t(1)$, plug the value of $q_t(1)$ you got in the ODE involving $q_t(2)$ and $q_t(1)$, solve this for $q_t(2)$, and so on. After a while, try to figure out a formula for $q_t(k)$ and check that this solves all the ODEs at once.

Comment: @Did, thanks for your reply but when I try to solve for $q_t(1) $ I get $1-exp(-\lambda t)$ and for $q_t(2)$ I get $2(\lambda t + exp(-\lambda t) -1)$ these seem wrong..

Comment: I do not know how you found THAT $q_t(1)$. See answer below.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments, an answer is

> Recursively: compute $q_t(0)$ (done), then plug it in the ODE involving $q_t(1)$ and $q_t(0)$, solve this for $q_t(1)$, plug the value of $q_t(1)$ you got in the ODE involving $q_t(2)$ and $q_t(1)$, solve this for $q_t(2)$, and so on. After a while, try to figure out a formula for $q_t(k)$ and check that this solves all the ODEs at once.

For example, the function $u$ defined by $u(t)=q_t(1)$ solves $u'(t)=-2\lambda u(t)+\lambda q_0(t)$ and $u(0)=0$, hence $(\mathrm e^{2\lambda t}u(t))'=\mathrm e^{2\lambda t}\lambda q_0(t)=\lambda \mathrm e^{\lambda t}$, which shows that $\mathrm e^{2\lambda t}u(t)=\mathrm e^{\lambda t}+C$ for some constant $C$. The initial condition $u(0)=0$ yields finally $q_t(1)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}-\mathrm e^{-2\lambda t}$.

Can you carry on?

Comment: thanks, I was missing the t's off the exponentials.